# Howto use svcutil to generate a C# WCF proxy from a web service that uses restriction to hide elements?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, schema, svcutil.exe

I'm creating a client to a web service that is more or less out of my control. Here is a simplified sample of the schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="element1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="element2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="A">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="element2" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

In short we have an object A that contains all elements. The service has several types based on A but with restrictions so that the inherited types are usually smaller than the base type - here exemplified by the type B.

In schema viewers like the one in Visual Studio 2010, SoapUI, etc. this looks as expected. A has 2 elements and B only 1 (= element 2).

By using svcutil I get the full set of elements in both my types A & B, or when playing with the options I get error messages such as:

> Error: Type 'B' in namespace 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd' cannot be imported. Complex types derived by restriction
>    not supported.  Either change the schema so that the types can map to data contract types or use ImportXmlType or use a
>    different serializer.

Hiding fields/properties in inherited types is not a practice/road I like to travel but if I cannot get the provider to change the WSDL it seems I have to do it that way.

**Is there alternatives to svcutil that handle this properly or do I have to hand-code my proxies?**

---

**Update 1**

As pointed out by John Saunders I have not shown the results of the suggestions from svcutil. That was partly to keep the post short... but here goes:

**svcutil schema.xsd /importXmlTypes /datacontractonly** results in:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="A", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")]
public partial class A : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private string element1Field;

    private string element2Field;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string element1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.element1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.element1Field = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string element2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.element2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.element2Field = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("ExportSchema")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable=false)]

public partial class B : object, System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
{

    private System.Xml.XmlNode[] nodesField;

    private static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeName = new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName("B", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");

    public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nodesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nodesField = value;
        }
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        this.nodesField = System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.ReadNodes(reader);
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.WriteNodes(writer, this.Nodes);
    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName ExportSchema(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.AddDefaultSchema(schemas, typeName);
        return typeName;
    }
}
```

Working on an Xml-level is not desirable and would force us to write a wrapper. It's easier to handcode the proxy from the getgo.

**svcutil schema.xsd /serializer:XmlSerializer /datacontractonly** Gives the error below and is the reason I'm asking for alternative tools.

> svcutil schema.xsd /serializer:XmlSerializer /datacontractonly
>   Error: Type 'B' in namespace 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd' cannot
>   be imported. Complex types derived by restriction not supported. 
>   Either change the schema so that the types can map to data contract
>   types or use ImportXmlType or use a different serializer.
>
> If you are using the /dataContractOnly option to import data contract
>   types and are getting this error message, consider using xsd.exe
>   instead. Types generated by xsd.exe may be used in the Windows
>   Communication Foundation after applying the
>   XmlSerializerFormatAttribute attribute on your service contract.
>   Alternatively, consider using the /importXmlTypes option to import
>   these types as XML types to use with DataContractFormatAttribute
>   attribute on your service contract.

Using **xsd schema.xsd /c** gives a type B that inherits A without hiding element1:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("request", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class B : A {
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(B))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")]
public partial class A {

    private string element1Field;

    private string element2Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string element1 {
        get {
            return this.element1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.element1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string element2 {
        get {
            return this.element2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.element2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of that error message didn't you understand? It told you exactly how to solve the problem.

Comment: No it does not give me the wanted result (also note I said messages such as - it was just a sample - a poor one I know...). If you have tried using those options you will see that it does not generate a proxy with the relevant properties. The result is that I end up with having to deal with lists of elements and serializtion directly.

Comment: I have no interest in trying those options. _You_ have tried them, and _you_ know the results. Please **show** us what you tried, and **show** us the results.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you to either use the `/importXmlTypes` switch, or to change to using the XmlSerializer. From the help:

> /importXmlTypes                    - Configure the Data Contract
>   serializer to import non-Data Contract types
>                                        as IXmlSerializable types.

and

> /serializer:XmlSerializer          - Generate data types that use the
>   XmlSerializer for serialization and
>                                        deserialization

Comment: Yes I know but doing so does not give me the wanted result of having a type B consisting of only the property named element2.

Comment: "Doing so?" Doing which of the _two_ things I showed you? What was the result? Update your question with the research you did and show us what the result was.